# estemating float string int type and length from orderdict variable data

Tags: python, variables, dictionary, fiona

OK this is a sort of strange question. Am using fiona (gis) which takes orderdict list as input for data and schema. The Schema tells fiona the name of variable and there type according to fiona. The data is in pandas after a join. I can output data in ordered dictionary or list. But from there how do if tell estimate the length an type of data to fiona using automation. There is something like this in messeytables but it is for csv and seems not a good way to go to start. This is an example of one ordereddict but there is lots of data. I am using fiona to do GIS stuff which it is good at.

this is the python mapping

```
'date': <class 'fiona.rfc3339.FionaDateType'>,
'datetime': <class 'fiona.rfc3339.FionaDateTimeType'>,
'float': <type 'float'>,
'int': <type 'int'>,
'str': <type 'unicode'>,
'time': <class 'fiona.rfc3339.FionaTimeType'>}
```

this is what a schema would looks like can be a list too

OrderedDict([(u'scalerank', 'int:4'), (u'featurecla', 'str:30'), (u'labelrank', 'float:16.6'), (u'sovereignt', 'str:254'), (u'sov_a3', 'str:254'), (u'adm0_dif', 'float:16.6'), (u'level', 'float:16.6'), (u'type', 'str:254'), (u'admin', 'str:254'), (u'adm0_a3', 'str:254'), (u'geou_dif', 'float:16.6'), (u'geounit', 'str:254'), (u'gu_a3', 'str:254'), (u'su_dif', 'float:16.6'), (u'subunit', 'str:254'), (u'su_a3', 'str:254'), (u'brk_diff', 'float:16.6'), (u'name', 'str:254'), (u'name_long', 'str:254'), (u'brk_a3', 'str:254'), (u'brk_name', 'str:254'), (u'brk_group', 'str:254'), (u'abbrev', 'str:254'), (u'postal', 'str:254'), (u'formal_en', 'str:254'), (u'formal_fr', 'str:254'), (u'note_adm0', 'str:254'), (u'note_brk', 'str:254'), (u'name_sort', 'str:254'), (u'name_alt', 'str:254'), (u'mapcolor7', 'float:16.6'), (u'mapcolor8', 'float:16.6'), (u'mapcolor9', 'float:16.6'), (u'mapcolor13', 'float:16.6'), (u'pop_est', 'float:16.6'), (u'gdp_md_est', 'float:16.6'), (u'pop_year', 'float:16.6'), (u'lastcensus', 'float:16.6'), (u'gdp_year', 'float:16.6'), (u'economy', 'str:254'), (u'income_grp', 'str:254'), (u'wikipedia', 'float:16.6'), (u'fips_10', 'str:254'), (u'iso_a2', 'str:254'), (u'iso_a3', 'str:254'), (u'iso_n3', 'str:254'), (u'un_a3', 'str:254'), (u'wb_a2', 'str:254'), (u'wb_a3', 'str:254'), (u'woe_id', 'float:16.6'), (u'adm0_a3_is', 'str:254'), (u'adm0_a3_us', 'str:254'), (u'adm0_a3_un', 'float:16.6'), (u'adm0_a3_wb', 'float:16.6'), (u'continent', 'str:254'), (u'region_un', 'str:254'), (u'subregion', 'str:254'), (u'region_wb', 'str:254'), (u'name_len', 'float:16.6'), (u'long_len', 'float:16.6'), (u'abbrev_len', 'float:16.6'), (u'tiny', 'float:16.6'), (u'homepart', 'float:16.6')])]

pandas output to ordereddict
OrderedDict([(u'scalerank', 1), (u'featurecla', u'Admin-0 map subunit'), (u'labelrank', 3.0), (u'sovereignt', u'Angola'), (u'sov_a3', u'AGO'), (u'adm0_dif', 0.0), (u'level', 2.0), (u'type', u'Sovereign country'), (u'admin', u'Angola'), (u'adm0_a3', u'AGO'), (u'geou_dif', 0.0), (u'geounit', u'Angola'), (u'gu_a3', u'AGO'), (u'su_dif', 0.0), (u'subunit', u'Angola'), (u'su_a3', u'AGO'), (u'brk_diff', 0.0), (u'name', u'Angola'), (u'name_long', u'Angola'), (u'brk_a3', u'AGO'), (u'brk_name', u'Angola'), (u'brk_group', None), (u'abbrev', u'Ang.'), (u'postal', u'AO'), (u'formal_en', u"People's Republic of Angola"), (u'formal_fr', None), (u'note_adm0', None), (u'note_brk', None), (u'name_sort', u'Angola'), (u'name_alt', None), (u'mapcolor7', 3.0), (u'mapcolor8', 2.0), (u'mapcolor9', 6.0), (u'mapcolor13', 1.0), (u'pop_est', 12799293.0), (u'gdp_md_est', 110300.0)

Comment: I'm not clear what your workflow is here. If your question is still unanswered, perhaps try rewording it? Also put 'pandas' in the keyword list. It seems you are asking if Pandas or Fiona has a way to do type-detection (string, float, integer) and field length similar to the way messytables can do on csv tables with type_guess, but you want a way to do this on a Python ordered dictionary?

Comment: Hi, I sort of figured it out. I just exported to Numpy recarray and got the dtype. From there I extracted and converted dtype to schema for fiona float64 to float16.6 or something like that. I think it is just a strange problem so hard to understand and maybe explain.